# Django/Async: When Using {%For Loop%}

Tags: django, async-await, fetch-api, async.js

I have working javascript in my Django code. The Javascript updates a field by fetching the field and passing the data as json to a view. Then it updates this field in the DB. The html contains a table and every time someone fills a form out a new row in the table is created.

Problem: It doesn't work when I use For Loops in my html code.

**What do I need to add to my javascript to get it to accept the code changes one at a time?**

Error: Unexpected Identifier:
let autosaveTimer;

```
 . . . 
<td>
<form action="  method='post' ">
{%csrf_token%}
<textarea name="cust_notes" maxlength="1000" required="" id="cust_notes"
class="form-control" value="">{{ x.cust_notes }}
</textarea>
</form>
</td>
. . . . 


 <script>
    const customerNoteInput = document.querySelector('#cust_notes');
    const notesEndpointURL = '/customers/notes/'
    const customerId = {{note.user_cust_id}}
    let autosaveTimer;

    customerNoteInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
        clearTimeout(autosaveTimer);

        autosaveTimer = setTimeout(autosaveNote, 2000);
    })


    function autosaveNote() {
        let noteText = customerNoteInput.value
        let data = {
            'user_cust_id': customerId,
            'cust_notes': noteText,
        }
        
        // Fetch API
        fetch(notesEndpointURL, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                console.log('Success! Response was 200!')
            }
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error: ', error)
        })
    
        console.log('Note autosaved:', customerNoteInput.value);
       
    }
</script>
```

```
def customer_note_endpoint(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        # When receiving json from Fetch API or "ajax", you get the data from request.body
        # To convert that json data into Python, import json and wrap request.body with json.loads
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        user_cust_id = int(data['user_cust_id'])
        customer_note_text = data['cust_notes']
        print('Note text:', customer_note_text)
        # Get user
        note = Note.objects.get(user_cust_id=user_cust_id)
        # Update their note text
        print('Old note text:', note.cust_notes)
        note.cust_notes = customer_note_text
        note.save()
        print('New note text:', note.cust_notes)
        # Save to the database
        note.save()

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Post successful!'})
  return JsonResponse({'message': 'INvalid method'}, status=405)
```